# Assign qr code generator to student result portal form

Tags: php, forms, qr-code

How do I assign qr code to user ID for login details

Comment: Your question is quite broad. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've done login form, registration form and profile page. The input on the login form is Matric/Roll Number which is unique for each student. So what I'm asking is how to generate qr code for each student that they'll use to login just as they're using their matric/roll num to login

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.